# File writing: display Unicode characters in finished file?

Tags: c#, json, unicode

I'm trying to create flash cards to memorise Japanese [kanji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanji) characters, and for that I'm crawling [Jitenon](https://kanji.jitenon.jp/), a website containing tons of kanji definitions, pronunciations and meanings. I've coded up the classes that would hold the relevant information that can be found on each kanji page, and I'm currently trying to save my list of kanji as a `json` file.

For testing purposes, I'm trying to parse individual kanji objects like this:

```cs
...
var kanji = scraper.GetKanjiDefinition(kanjiUrl);
var jsonOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions() { WriteIndented = true };
var kanjiJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(kanji, jsonOptions);
File.WriteAllText("kanji_json.json", kanjiJson, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Here's an [example page](https://kanji.jitenon.jp/kanji/098.html) that I've crawled with its corresponding `json` serialization:

```json
{
  "Character": "\u697D",
  "MainRadical": "\u6728",
  "Strokes": 13,
  "KankenLevel": "\uFF19\u7D1A",
  "Education": "\u5C0F\u5B66\u6821\uFF12\u5E74\u751F",
  "Meanings": [
    {
      "Indices": [
        "\u301C"
      ],
      "Meaning": "\u304A\u3093\u304C\u304F\u3002",
      "JapanTypical": false
    },
    {
      "Indices": [
        "\u301C"
      ],
      "Meaning": "\u304B\u306A\u3067\u308B\u3002\u97F3\u3092\u304B\u306A\u3067\u308B\u3002\u6F14\u594F\u3059\u308B\u3002",
      "JapanTypical": false
    },
    {
      "Indices": [
        "\u301C"
      ],
      "Meaning": "\u305F\u306E\u3057\u3044\u3002\u305F\u306E\u3057\u3080\u3002\u3088\u308D\u3053\u3076\u3002",
      "JapanTypical": false
    },
    {
      "Indices": [
        "\u301C"
      ],
      "Meaning": "\u3053\u306E\u3080\u3002\u611B\u3059\u308B\u3002\u306D\u304C\u3046\u3002\u6C42\u3081\u308B\u3002",
      "JapanTypical": false
    },
    {
      "Indices": [],
      "Meaning": "\u65E5\u672C\u3089\u304F\u3002\u305F\u3084\u3059\u3044\u3002\u5FC3\u8EAB\u306B\u82E6\u75DB\u304C\u306A\u304F\u3001\u306E\u3073\u306E\u3073\u3059\u308B\u3002",
      "JapanTypical": true
    }
  ],
  "Readings": [
    {
      "Reading": "\u30AC\u30AF",
      "Yomi": 0,
      "MeaningIndices": [
        1
      ],
      "Education": "\u5C0F"
    },
    {
      "Reading": "\u30E9\u30AF",
      "Yomi": 0,
      "MeaningIndices": [
        2
      ],
      "Education": "\u5C0F"
    },
    {
      "Reading": "\u30AE\u30E7\u30A6",
      "Yomi": 0,
      "MeaningIndices": [
        3
      ],
      "Education": "\u5C0F"
    },
    {
      "Reading": "\u30B4\u30A6",
      "Yomi": 0,
      "MeaningIndices": [
        3
      ],
      "Education": "\u5C0F"
    },
    {
      "Reading": "\u305F\u306E\uFF08\u3057\u3044\uFF09",
      "Yomi": 1,
      "MeaningIndices": [],
      "Education": "\u5C0F"
    },
    {
      "Reading": "\u305F\u306E\uFF08\u3057\u3080\uFF09",
      "Yomi": 1,
      "MeaningIndices": [],
      "Education": "\u5C0F"
    },
    {
      "Reading": "\u304B\u306A\uFF08\u3067\u308B\uFF09",
      "Yomi": 1,
      "MeaningIndices": [],
      "Education": "\u5C0F"
    },
    {
      "Reading": "\u3053\u306E\uFF08\u3080\uFF09",
      "Yomi": 1,
      "MeaningIndices": [],
      "Education": "\u5C0F"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd like to have the actual Japanese text included in the `json` file, for example `"Character": "楽"` and `"MainRadical": "木"` and `"KankenLevel": "９級"` instead of the escaped Unicode characters like `\u697D`. How could I achieve this in .NET?

If it makes any difference, I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and I open my `json` files in VS Code 1.56.2.

Comment: You can't.  Html doesn't allow special characters.  You either need to use the unicode value or the names.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the [Encoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-character-encoding) in your jsonOptions:

```
var jsonOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions() { 
    Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.Create(UnicodeRanges.All),
    WriteIndented = true 
};
```

The above one allows all [UnicodeRanges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.unicode.unicoderanges.all?view=net-5.0#System_Text_Unicode_UnicodeRanges_All)

Comment: How does doing it this way compare to using `Regex.Unescape` as mentioned in the comments?

Comment: @JansthcirlU RegEx is a hack. You have an encoding problem, those are dealt with by selecting a proper encoder. These mechanisms are build in the framework,  tested, tuned and comply to the applicable standards. Serializing is with an encoder is probably faster or at least more memory efficient then running a regex after the fact (let alone debugging it when the regex fails on corner cases).